# Perform a task 'n' times in parallel

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, java.util.concurrent

I am trying to figure out the easiest way to invoke a task 'x' times and all in parallel in java. The task has a string variable whose value should be unique for each invocation and it returns a string and int result.

I have been looking up resources in internet and now I am terribly confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to execute tasks in parallel, your first choice should be an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).
You get an instance of one like they say in the docs, that is

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
```

If your tasks must return a value, you should use the

```
Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task);
```

function. Make your tasks implement the `Callable` interface, returning the result you require. Submit your tasks to the service, then wait for the results through the `Future` objects. A rough sketch:

```
public class MyTask implements Callable<StringInt> {
    public MyTask(String inputParameter) { ... }
    public StringInt call() { ... }
}

...

List<Future<StringInt>> results = new ArrayList<Future<StringInt>>();
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(16);
for (String inputParameter : inputParameters) {
    // Create tasks and start parallel execution
    results.add(service.submit(new MyTask(inputParameter)));
}

for (Future<StringInt> result : results) {
    // Wait for tasks to end, and get result
    StringInt resultValue = result.get();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now, if I wanted to program it such that the code doesn't wait for all the threads to finish, ie: I'd want the threads to return as and when they complete, which is the class I am suppose to use?

Comment: If you mean that you want to submit all tasks, then retrieve results in the order they are produced, you can use CompletionService: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html